# Не входит в django administation

Tags: django, django-admin

После моего усовершенствования формы регистрации на сайте с помощью модуля django-user-accounts (я добавил поле с e-mail-адресом и отправку писем с подтверждением), я не смог войти в django administation.

> Пожалуйста, введите корректные имя пользователя и пароль учётной
>   записи. Оба поля могут быть чувствительны к регистру.

Я создал нового суперюзера, увидел сообщение:

> Superuser created successfully.

Но результат остался тем же.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему путем добавления следующей строки в settings.py.

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
     ...
]
```